# Apache Commons Net FTPClient - PUT instead of STOR?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am using the Apache commons net FTPClient to distribute files as part of batch jobs. The client is encapsulated, but roughly I issue the following method calls (i have omitted error handling, stream handling etc. for brevity):

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect("127.0.0.1", 22);
client.login("user", "password");
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
client.changeWorkingDirectory("path/");
client.storeFile("file1.txt", new ByteArrayInputStream("hello world".getBytes()));
client.disconnect();
```

When I issue the commands above, The following commands are sent to the FTP server:

```
USER zoor
PASS ********
TYPE I
CWD path/
PORT 127,0,0,1,229,72
STOR file1.txt
```

And this works fine. Now, however, I am in a situation where i need to send files to a legacy system which does not support `CWD` or `STOR` but instead relies on `CD` and `PUT`, respectively..

Now my question is, how do I make the FTPClient use these commands?

I could use the `sendCommand` method to send the `CD` command, but I am not sure how to do this properly (and correctly) with the PUT command (given that I must send the file data also).

NOTE: I realize that there are better ways than FTP to distribute files like this, but unfortunately, my hands are bound. The recipients are using FTP and are not willing to change.

**UPDATE:** The legacy system is an AS/400 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me that CD and PUT are not actually FTP commands and as such the question makes little sense.. The solution (because we need it to work ASAP) is that we transfer the files to our own FTP server, and call a script via SSH on that server that transfers the files to the AS/400 machine.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, I understand you worked around the issue, but for sake of completeness, do you know if AS/400 needs any site commands to store the file.

What is the error your getting back?

I regularly send files to MVS / Z/OS and there are a few site commands that need to be sent first for storage and setup.

Site commands would look something like:

- TRAIL
- CYLINDERS PRIMARY=350 SECONDARY=300
- RECFM=FB LRECL=1516 BLKSIZE=31836
- CONDDISP=delete

Here's a little code that I use, ftp is essentially the FTPClient that you use in your example.

```
    public boolean sendSiteCommand(String siteCmd){
    if (null == siteCmd){
        System.err.println("Warning, Null Parameter sent to sendSiteCommand, aborting...");
        return false;
    }

    try{

        return ftp.sendSiteCommand(siteCmd);

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error Occurred Sending Site Command to Remote System, aborting...");
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the site command myself, however this was not needed in my case... The error was that CWD and STOR were not recognized when i logged into the server via FTP... As far as I could understand from the AS/400 documentation, you talk to an FTP client which understand the CD/PUT commands, and when you issue such a command, it will talk to an FTP server, to which it sends CWD and STOR command.. However, I could not talk to the server directly, and therefore could not use the actual FTP commands to upload a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need to upload a file as another command, you can always extend `FTPClient` and call the internal methods with a different command. They are built that you can give any string as the command to the already existing stores.

Example:

```
    public static class OldFtpClient extends FTPClient {
        public OutputStream putFileStream(String remote) throws IOException {
            return _storeFileStream("PUT", remote);
        }
    }
```

Source of class can be found at https://github.com/apache/commons-net/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.java .